# AWS CodeDeploy keeps running as root, breaks after first run

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

Previously I had CodeDeploy running properly as user www-data and everything was fine but I think CodeDeploy got corrupted somehow because it always runs as the root user now.  Then, it breaks mid-deploy because of the "wrong permissions" because it shouldn't try to run as the root user, but the www-data user.

I checked another working server with a working CodeDeploy setup and the settings match EXCEPT there are no root user entries after running "ps aux | grep codedeploy-agent" seen here:

[image: CodeDeploy]

CodeDeploy says here that it's running as PID 3914 - so why is there a root entry with PID 3650?  I think it is also using the root entry PID 3650 when running CodeDeploy because it is creating new directories with "root:root" permissions.  However on the working servers, everything is created with "www-data:wheel" as I configured it.

So, how can I remove the root user here from executing everything without breaking anything else? (I prefer not to delete stuff without knowing if it's safe and this is also a server that another team works on so I am trying to avoid a full rebuild or uninstall - as well as breaking any of their stuff.)

FYI to get this working in the first place as www-data running CodeDeploy, I changed the user using this article and it's worked great on other servers for months now: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/codedeploy-agent-non-root-profile/

*Note: Tried deleting the .pid and .pid.lock files recommended in another post and printed in screenshot, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would come down to an update to the CodeDeploy agent. Possibly either an accidental replacement in the update process or incompatible changes which required settings to be reset to the default settings.

I would suggest leaving these default settings for CodeDeploy as it can be reconfigured during patching or future updates (which leaves it out of your control). Instead set permissions via the [appspec file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html).

You can define the users that actions within CodeDeploy run as via the appspec file that is required for each deployed.

By specifying `runas` the hook will be run as that user, as seen in this example below.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: Config/config.txt
    destination: /webapps/Config
  - source: source
    destination: /webapps/myApp
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: Scripts/UnzipResourceBundle.sh
    - location: Scripts/UnzipDataBundle.sh
  AfterInstall:
    - location: Scripts/RunResourceTests.sh
      timeout: 180
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: Scripts/RunFunctionalTests.sh
      timeout: 3600
  ValidateService:
    - location: Scripts/MonitorService.sh
      timeout: 3600
      runas: codedeployuser
```

You can also set the [permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-permissions.html) that particular directories or files have (from the `files` hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the note about patching or future updates, Chris! Discovered that AWS automatic updates (that I didn't even know were set to happen or know what they did) have reset/removed previous configurations when the instance was first created.  Once I re-ran all the those server configurations (like sudo access) everything worked again - so it is the AWS updates that broke things.  Not sure if there is a place I can check for these AWS updates to make a note?  I like your CodeDeploy suggestion, too. TY

Comment: As the installer is provided by AWS, I would assume it would retain configuration but I would guess sometimes breaking changes might reset this. You'd probably have to disable the auto update and then manually update (with applying the config changes again after) which is not ideal as it is manual intervention :(

Comment: Yeah, I definitely do not want to disable updates.  I just need to get my scripts on a cron job or something every day?  I think it's just sudo access that was cut off from the updates because it deleted my custom sudo file in /etc/sudoers.d

Comment: Also, not sure if you can resubmit your answer in different wording so that I can mark as correct? CodeDeploy ran as root because AWS updates broke previous server configurations by resetting them and then CodeDeploy user www-data lost sudo access.  Once the server was reconfigured with permissions, it worked!

Comment: @ForeverLearningAndCoding updated answer to make it more obvious :)

Comment: I would definitely suggest still using Code Deploy @ForeverLearningAndCoding, just use the appspec to define permissions of your Codebase :)